# If else in React Native with more than 2 conditions

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to React Native so I am not sure if the if else function works but I tried the following code. LayoutAngle is a user input. So when I keep in 30, I was expecting a1 = 1, a2 = 1, a3 = 1 and a4 = 1. However, that is error occurring, stating that can't find variable a1.

```
if (LayoutAngle === "30") {
            a1 = 1
            a2 = 1
            a3 = 1
            a4 = 1
        }
if (LayoutAngle === "60") {
            a1 = 2
            a2 = 2
            a3 = 2
            a4 = 2
        }
if (LayoutAngle === "30") {
            a1 = 3
            a2 = 3
            a3 = 3
            a4 = 3
        }
        else return(null)

const a = a3/(1-(0.14)*Math.pow(10,a4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use switch-case for your problem.

```
switch (LayoutAngle) {
    case '30':
      //Some code here
      break;
    case '60':
      //Some code here
      break;
    case '30':
      //Some code here
      break;
    default:
      return null;
  }
```